# My keyboard won't type the key that I hold when I pressed other key simultaneously

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, logitech-keyboard

My keyboard is Logitech G813 with  Windows 10 Pro, whenever I hold a certain key on my keyboard and then pressed other key once while holding that certain key, it will stop typing even while holding it. For example, I hold the key <kbd>j</kbd>, so it will type "jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj" but when I interrupt it with letter `k` it will be "jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjk" then it will stop typing "jjjjjj" again, I need to hold it again. What I want is to press it like "jjjjjjjjjjjkjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjkjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj", while holding the <kbd>J</kbd> button.

I tried other keyboards on my desktop computer, it still doesn't work. But when I tried it with my Laptop, it works perfectly fine. When I hold <kbd>J</kbd>, and interrupts with other key simultaneously, it will continue on typing `J` after that. No need to re-press it.

Comment: Please explain your use case or what you want to achieve. Maybe you need a different way to get the keyboard events, e.g. key J press, ... key K press, key K release, ... key J release.

Comment: I use it to spam my skills in a game LOL, I hold 1 key then when I press other key, the one that Im holding stops functioning. Right now Im using the Macro Key to do that, but its nicer if I can use it in my normal keys.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

Ever since the first IBM PC, keyboards only send repeated key press events only from the very last last key that is pressed and held down. When this key is released, no repeating key press events from other previously held keys should be sent, except for the release events.

I don't know why your laptop does it then, it really should not.

Comment: I see, I use it for my games, and this is the only time i get problem like this. Thats why I'm not used that its not functioning like I expected.

Comment: Games handle keyboard directly. They tend to keep track of the key press and release events themselves. So expect different programs to behave differently than others.